# Trouble installing Meteor on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, meteor

I see many people have had issues installing Meteor on Ubuntu before me, but I haven't seen the particular error I get on here yet, so I'm making a new post.
When I execute:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

I get:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file /home/ubuntu/.meteor-tarball-tmp:          
Warning: Permission denied
                                                                           
0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

If any of you know how to solve this, please let me know

Comment: Have you tried `sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

Comment: Your home directory (assuming you are user `ubuntu`) seems to not be owned by you. Try `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu`, and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your home directory (assuming you are user `ubuntu`) seems to not be owned by you. Try `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu`, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same error when running...

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

... on a newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 system. After trying and failing with a number of simpler approaches, including those suggested by Minh Nguyen and Christian Fritz here, I eventually opted for the following manual installation process.

1. I visited https://install.meteor.com/ in my browser and copied-and-pasted the installation script into my text editor.
2. I saved the file as `meteor-install.sh`
3. I ran the script in debug mode from the Terminal: `bash -x ./meteor-install.sh`
4. In the output in the Terminal window, I found the lines:

```sh
+ curl --progress-bar --fail --continue-at - https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.meteor.static/packages-bootstrap/2.3.4/meteor-bootstrap-os.linux.x86_64.tar.gz --output /home/blackslate/.meteor-tarball-tmp
curl: Can't open '/home/blackslate/.meteor-tarball-tmp'!
```

5. This gave me the link to the file that the script was failing to download. In my case, this was `https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.meteor.static/packages-bootstrap/2.3.4/meteor-bootstrap-os.linux.x86_64.tar.gz`, but you might have a different value for the Release number (2.3.4) and the OS (linux).
6. I downloaded this file and extracted its contents: a hidden folder with the name `.meteor`
7. I used `mv .meteor "$HOME"` to move it to my Home folder.
8. After the installation script has done all these steps, it then sets up a number of symbolic links and a launcher script. I removed all the lines of code from the `meteor-install.sh` script that handled the steps that I had just completed manually, and then ran the remainder of the script, as shown below. (Lines with `# ...` indicate where I have removed code).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# ...
run_it () {
# ...
RELEASE="2.3.4"
# ...
PREFIX="/usr/local"
# ...
# just double-checking :)
test -x "$HOME/.meteor/meteor"
# ...

echo
echo "Meteor ${RELEASE} has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor)."

METEOR_SYMLINK_TARGET="$(readlink "$HOME/.meteor/meteor")"
METEOR_TOOL_DIRECTORY="$(dirname "$METEOR_SYMLINK_TARGET")"
LAUNCHER="$HOME/.meteor/$METEOR_TOOL_DIRECTORY/scripts/admin/launch-meteor"

if cp "$LAUNCHER" "$PREFIX/bin/meteor" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Writing a launcher script to $PREFIX/bin/meteor for your convenience."
  cat <<"EOF"

To get started fast:

  $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
  $ cd ~/my_cool_app
  $ meteor

Or see the docs at:

  docs.meteor.com

Deploy and host your app with Cloud:

  www.meteor.com/cloud

EOF
elif type sudo >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Writing a launcher script to $PREFIX/bin/meteor for your convenience."
  echo "This may prompt for your password."

  # New macs (10.9+) don't ship with /usr/local, however it is still in
  # the default PATH. We still install there, we just need to create the
  # directory first.
  # XXX this means that we can run sudo too many times. we should never
  #     run it more than once if it fails the first time
  if [ ! -d "$PREFIX/bin" ] ; then
      sudo mkdir -m 755 "$PREFIX" || true
      sudo mkdir -m 755 "$PREFIX/bin" || true
  fi

  if sudo cp "$LAUNCHER" "$PREFIX/bin/meteor"; then
    cat <<"EOF"

To get started fast:

  $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
  $ cd ~/my_cool_app
  $ meteor

Or see the docs at:

  docs.meteor.com

Deploy and host your app with Cloud:

  www.meteor.com/cloud

EOF
  else
    cat <<EOF

Couldn't write the launcher script. Please either:

  (1) Run the following as root:
        cp "$LAUNCHER" /usr/bin/meteor
  (2) Add "\$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (3) Rerun this command to try again.

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.
EOF
  fi
else
  cat <<EOF

Now you need to do one of the following:

  (1) Add "\$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (2) Run this command as root:
        cp "$LAUNCHER" /usr/bin/meteor

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.
EOF
fi


trap - EXIT
}

run_it
```

9. To check that all was working, I ran the following commands in the Terminal...

   meteor create test
   ... 
   cd test
   meteor

... and checked that the default Meteor app was indeed running at http://localhost:3000/

But all this fails to answer the question: Why is `Permission denied` on the file `/home/<username>/.meteor-tarball-tmp`, when this file is created by a process run by `<username>`?